# How parse xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<srl>

<role>V</role><txt>Representava</txt>
<role>A2</role><txt>ela</txt>
<role>A1</role>
<txt>uma jibóia
    <role>A0</role><txt>que</txt>
    <role>V</role><txt>engolia</txt>
    <role>A1</role><txt>uma fera</txt>
</txt>
</srl>
```

How do I extract just this block in python? I'm using Beautiful Soup.

```
<txt>uma jibóia
    <role>A0</role><txt>que</txt>
    <role>V</role><txt>engolia</txt>
    <role>A1</role><txt>uma fera</txt>
</txt>
```

I tried this:

```
soup = bs(open(xml, 'r'), 'lxml')
texts = soup.find_all('txt')

for t in texts:
    print t.text
```

Comment: That's not a  balanced chunk. Do you want just the `<txt>` branch?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried.

Comment: Yes. And the role too.

Comment: soup = bs(open(xml,'r'),'lxml')  txts = soup.find_all('txt')

Comment: Then, please, remove the `</srl>` in the expected output

Comment: I know you've commented it but you should consider putting what you've tried in your question and formatting it like you did with the XML.

Comment: what wrong with your code ? did you get error message ? Put it in question.

Comment: `print(texts[2])` or `data = str(texts[2])`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
for t in texts:
    if len(t.contents) > 1:
       print t
```